# About C++ Primer(5th) exercise 13.13 a question

Tags: c++

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct X
{
    X() { cout << "X()" << endl; }
    X( const string &s ):item( s ) { cout << "X( initialize by str(" << s << ") )" << endl; }
    X( const& X ) { cout << "X( const X& )" << endl; }
    ~X() { cout << "X(" << (*this).item << ") was destroy" << endl; }

    string item;
};

int main()
{

    X a( "aa" );
    X b( "bb" );
    X c( "cc" );

    vector<X> vec;

    vec.push_back( a );
    vec.push_back( b );
    vec.push_back( c );

    vec[0].item = "vec_aa";
    vec[1].item = "vec_bb";
    vec[2].item = "vec_cc";

}
```

When I run the program, I get this output:

X( initialize by str(aa) )
X( initialize by str(bb) )
X( initialize by str(cc) )
X(aa) was destroy
X(aa) was destroy
X(bb) was destroy
X(vec_aa) was destroy
X(vec_bb) was destroy
X(vec_cc) was destroy
X(cc) was destroy
X(bb) was destroy
X(aa) was destroy

So, my question: Why did it output

```
X(aa) was destroy  
X(aa) was destroy  
X(bb) was destroy
```

I expected the output to be

```
X(aa) was destroy  
X(bb) was destroy  
X(cc) was destroy
```

Comment: That duplicate doesn't answer the op's question... it's to do with the `vector` reallocating on the second `push_back` call.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/Gnznc4Pah. In your output, copy constructor calls are missing. Also, you have a typo there, should be `const X&`. Copy constructor should also copy `item`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` resides in contiguous memory - and if that's not large enough any more it needs to be re-sized, meaning allocating new memory, move (if available) or copy construct the objects in the new memory and destroy those in the old one, before it gets deleted.

Obviously such a re-allocation occurs twice, that's where your unexpected output comes from:

```
X(aa) was destroy // first re-allocation: copy of aa resides in vector with
                  // capacity of size 1, but needs to be 2

X(aa) was destroy // second re-allocation: copies of aa and bb reside in
X(bb) was destroy // vector with capacity of 2, but needs to be 3
                  // (will, most likely, actually get 4)
```

You can avoid that if you [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) sufficient memory in advance – which is what you should *always* do if you know in advance (even if only roughly) how many objects you are going to place into the vector as re-allocations are expensive.